# Combine two arrays into one array by picking keys & values randomly from two different arrays

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arr1 = array(
   "William",
    "Henry",
    "Filbert",
    "John",
    "Pat",
);

$arr2 = array(
   "Smith",
    "Jones",
    "Winkler",
    "Cooper",
    "Cline",
);
```

I want to combine these 2 arrays into 1 array to get `First Name => Last Name` combinations. Now I do not want to just loop through one array and then another. I want to pick random first names from $arr1, then pick random last names from $arr2 and combine them.

My approach is this:

```
shuffle($arr1);
shuffle($arr2);
$arr3 = array_combine($arr1, $arr2);
```

Is my approach correct or is there a better way of doing this? I need a way to handle duplicate values as well.

Comment: Are you trying to make a list of every combination possible or just a simple mixed/random list of possibilities? There's several ways to do this. What you have will work so long you know how to use `$arr3`.

Comment: How can there be duplicate values? You mean somebody with the same first and last name?

Comment: @HalfCrazed Either one works for me. Most likely just combining 2 arrays will suffice for my application.

Comment: @nikola if someone has same first name (key) in array, the second one will overwrite

Comment: @GGio okay so you can't use last name as key then

Answer (score 1):

```
shuffle( $arr1 );
shuffle( $arr2 );

$out = array_map( function( $a, $b ) { return array( 'first' => $a, 'last' => $b ); }, $arr1, $arr2 );

/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [first] => Pat
            [last] => Smith
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [first] => William
            [last] => Cooper
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [first] => Filbert
            [last] => Cline
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [first] => Henry
            [last] => Jones
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [first] => John
            [last] => Winkler
        )

)
```

Comment: but this does not do random selection. This just maps first element from array 1 to first element to array 2

Comment: You can always do `$name = $out[mt_rand(0, count($out) - 1)]` after mapping.